# Distributing positive numbers accordingly through textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, numbers

I made a program that the number I inputted on the textbox will be distributed in each textboxes accordingly with a press of a button (eg."GO"). The numbers that will be displayed will be positive, and the negative numbers are dropped(it will not be displayed).

With a total of 6 textboxes
1-input, and 5-output and a button.

The output should be,

input:12

-[*Press GO*]-

box1: 12

input:22

-[*Press GO*]-

box2: 22

etc...

```
int[] posno={0,0,0,0,0};
    private void gobtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int input;
        input = Int32.Parse(num.Text);
        for (int x = 0; x <= 4; x++)
        {
            if (input >= 0)
                posno[x] = input;
            num.Clear();
            num.Focus();
            no1.Text = posno[0].ToString();
            no2.Text = posno[1].ToString();
            no3.Text = posno[2].ToString();
            no4.Text = posno[3].ToString();
            no5.Text = posno[4].ToString();
        }
    }
```

I can't seem to distribute the numbers accordingly, are there ways on how to do that?

Comment: So, basically you want to enter a number in `num` and when you hit `Go` you want to put that number  in the textboxes `no1` through `no5` (unless the number is less than 0)?

Comment: Yes please help me ;(

Comment: What's wrong with your code? What happens and what did you expect?

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer (because I don't see what's functionally wrong with your code) but your code can be cleaner:

```
int[] posno={0,0,0,0,0};

private void gobtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int input;
    input = Int32.Parse(num.Text);

    if (input >= 0)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++) 
        {
            posno[x] = input;
        }
        no1.Text = posno[0].ToString();
        no2.Text = posno[1].ToString();
        no3.Text = posno[2].ToString();
        no4.Text = posno[3].ToString();
        no5.Text = posno[4].ToString();
    }
    num.Clear();
    num.Focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be done a bit differently

```
int[] posno={0,0,0,0,0};
int lastInput = 0;
    private void gobtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int input = Int32.Parse(num.Text);
        if (input >= 0)
        {
            posno[lastInput] = input;
            lastInput++;
            //reset counter
            if (lastInput = 5) 
            { 
                lastInput = 0; 
            }
        }
        no1.Text = posno[0].ToString();
        no2.Text = posno[1].ToString();
        no3.Text = posno[2].ToString();
        no4.Text = posno[3].ToString();
        no5.Text = posno[4].ToString();
    }
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clearly stated, but let's see if I understand what you're trying to achieve.

You have an "input" TextBox, and 5 "output" TextBoxes.

You want that each time you click the "GO" Button, the value in the input TextBox should be written to an output TextBox, in sequence, meaning that the first time you click GO, the value should go to output TextBox1 and so on.

Based on this assumption, here's one way to achieve this. It is based on having your TextBoxes named sequentially, such as tbOutput1, tbOutput2 and so on.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int index;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ResetForm();
    }

    private void ResetForm()
    {
        index = 1;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb = this.Controls.Find("tbOutput" + index.ToString(), false).OfType<TextBox>().FirstOrDefault();
        if(tb!= null)
        {
            tb.Text = tbInput.Text;
        }
        index++;
        if (index > 5)
            ResetForm();
    }
}
```

I am also assuming that you want to "cycle" so that when you reach #5, then you should go back to #1. If not, then simply modify the code accordingly.

So, the general idea is to maintain the "state" of your index as a class member so that it is retained in between calls to your button's click event handler.

Then , using the ControlsCollection.Find() method, which can find a Form's control based on its name, you get a reference to the textbox corresponding to the index. I'm using a bit of Linq to "massage" the return from Find() to a TextBox, as Find() returns an array of Control objects.

If this is not what you're trying to do, please clarify your question.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

to put it across, what I mean is:

```
inputbox: 10   [go]    outputbox1: 10
inputbox: 2    [go]    outputbox2: 2
inputbox: 4    [go]    outputbox3: 4
inputbox: -2   [go]    (no output)
inputbox: -3   [go]    (no output)
inputbox: 33   [go]    outputbox4: 33
inputbox: 46   [go]    outputbox5: 46

so, the outcome will be: 10, 2, 4, 33, 46
```

to understand my question fully, the design of my program is here: [Design View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMNMV.png)

I'm sorry if you didn't understand my question